# C++ Windows Console Color Palette

Tags: c++, winapi, colors, console

I am making a console application similar to a rudimentary AAlib for a class. I am working with the win32 console. I wish to have more colors to work with. In the properties menu for the console there is a palette, giving 24 bit colors to foreground and background. Is there any way to access this palette in code?

The only thing I can think of is redefining the color palette[n] in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console for each call to color a character.

Alternatively if anyone knows a method for printing to window class like a terminal(where each character could have background color, not a fill) that could also work.

Comment: Can haz only 16 distinct colors.  You change the palette with SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx().  Clearly you are about ready to leave the confines of the 1970s terminal I/O model and move to creating true windows.  Using 16 million distinct colors and printing certainly is not a problem when you do.

Comment: Your right, I thought I could get around it by changing the colors in registry but each time will reset how all past colors printed are displayed.